# mask a xarray.dataset using nan values in another dataset

Tags: dataset, nan, mask, python-xarray

I have a dataset (named ds1) that includes HWI (heatwave index) data variable with dimensions of time: 365, latitude: 681, longitude: 841
[image]

I want to mask ds1 by using ds2 which has the same dimensions but has nan values over the ocean grids:
[image]

How can I mask ds1 using nan values in ds2?

I have tried several ways but all failed like this:

```
mask = np.isnan(ds2.HWI[:,:,:])
ds1.HWI[mask]=np.nan
```

this code returns the error that: IndexError: 3-dimensional boolean indexing is not supported.

```
ds1_mask = ds1.where(ds2.isnull())
```

error: IndexError: The indexing operation you are attempting to perform is not valid on netCDF4.Variable object. Try loading your data into memory first by calling .load().

when I first load ds1 and ds2 into memory and then run:

```
ds1_mask = ds1['HWI'].where(np.isnan(ds2['HWI']))
```

then I don't get any error message but the final ds1_mask dataarray is weird since it includes four lat and lon dimensions with a time dimension of zero! like this:
[image]

any tip or idea is much appreciated!

Comment: I suspect the problem may have something to do with the fact that your "latitude" dimension has different names in the two different datasets.

Comment: `ds1.where(ds2.HWI.isnull())` should then work, I think.

Comment: But I would really like to know where the `IndexError: The indexing operation you are attempting to perform is not valid on netCDF4.Variable object. Try loading your data into memory first by calling .load().` comes from